# Google Analytics vs Flurry Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, flurry

In my app:

Flurry is showing over 11,000 new users.

I also have google analytics in the app too and that is showing 8,200 unique visitors.

Has anyone got experience of this and could lead me in the direction of a solution to why there is this discrepancy in numbers.

Thanks

Comment: Do the trends at least look similar? All reporting tools have different counting methodologies, so if your trends are similar I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: I wouldn't worry if it wasn't such a large number - 2,800 missing users - or extra users.

Comment: I discovered that whoever setup our Google account set it up as a 'Web ' profile and not an 'App' profile. And in googles best practice guide, it states that if you do this, the results are unpredictable! I might add this as the answer for this particular problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I discovered that whoever setup our Google account set it up as a 'Web ' profile and not an 'App' profile. And in googles best practice guide, it states that if you do this, the results are unpredictable! I might add this as the answer for this particular problem

Comment: How can count all app installs without play store help from Flurry or Analytics. I mean not active users, Installed or first open users.

Answer (score 30):

There are 2 key differences in the way Flurry and Google Analytics report "New Users".

1) Flurry looks at unique devices, and not user IDs. That means that if a user uses the same user ID to install the app on multiple devices, Google will count it as 1 Sale, whereas Flurry will count it as multiple "New Users".

2) Flurry counts a user only when they have launched the app, not upon install. Which means that if Google Analytics report an "install" today, but the user launches the app tomorrow, Flurry system will count it as a New User tomorrow.

Full disclosure: I work at Flurry

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not sure that you're correct. Regarding point 1: How does google have a concept of a user when I download from the app store and install on my iPhone and iPad? I don't believe they can distinguish that I'm the same person. Regarding point 2 - GA can only report an install when the users launches the app too.

Comment: Hi Aman, thanks for the info. Regarding your second point , how we can report an app is installed without opening it. Because we are creating the session in the App launch method. Note:- In case of iOS i think it is not possible to send an information when an app is installed. There will be some kind of restrictions. right?

Comment: @bandejapaisa on Android Google Analytics is highly integrated with Google Play Services and thus able to detect new users when the app is installed but not opened. This is only valid for devices on which the Play Services app is installed.

Comment: Where can get app installs in flurry? I count app installs in FireBase with first_open_event, I do not know is it reliable or not.